# How to build a Function object that accesses outside variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a need to execute code contained within a string, and in keeping with [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) that instructs using a Function object instead of eval(), I wrote the following code (simplified):

```js
const a = 10;
const b = 10;

function convertCodeToObject(code)
{
    return Function('"use strict"; return (' + code + ');')();
}

function main()
{
    const c = convertCodeToObject('a + b');
    console.log(c);
}

main()
```

As you can see it runs fine and outputs 20.

My environment is a little more complex and I use ES6 and Webpack. This appears to affect this use-case because I'm receiving the following error:

`a is not defined`

Any idea why I would be having this problem?

Comment: The `Function` constructor creates a function that doesn't run in the local context. As such, it's not really possible to do what you want aside from putting everything in the global context which is a bad idea. However, this seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what exactly are you trying to do and why do you need automatic code generation for it? Can you not use more well established way to generate new functions?

Comment: @VLAZ I apologize for my noobness in JS, I haven't used it in more than a decade. In my example, I thought a and b were in the global context? Are you saying that ES6 and/or Webpack create a different context and that is the reason why it works as standalone code in the snippet, and not in my environment? Possible to pass the current context through bind()? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: @VLAZ In my specific case there aren't too many alternatives, I'm sending snippets of JS code as strings from C#.

Comment: Re global context - `a` and `b` would be isolated from it. Any bundlers will try to ensure it using *at the very least* the [module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) which involves wrapping code in a functional context, therefore removing it from the global one. This is a good practice, since it ensures that two different modules will not clash if they re-use the same variable name. Nowadays there is direct support for [standartised modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) that do the same.

Comment: As for alternatives - without knowing *what* you're trying to do, I can't really suggest any. However, I do think that there are better ways than trying to dynamically evaluate code. You can very simply define your functions on the front end, e.g., `add`, and `subtract` and then the backend can send over function name with parameters, e.g., `["add", "price", "VAT"]`. This will allow you to have a strict verification for correctness and then a safe execution as you are certain the operation *and* operands are correct. It's also possible you don't need any of that - I can't really say.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following tests:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function test1()
    {
        var a = 1, b = 1;
        function run(code)
        {
            var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })();
            console.log("test 1 is strict: " + isStrict);
            return eval(code);
        }
        return run("a+b");
    }

    function test2()
    {
        var a = 1, b = 1;
        function run(code)
        {
            "use strict";
            var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })();
            console.log("test 2 is strict: " + isStrict);
            return eval(code);
        }
        return run("a+b");
    }

    function test3()
    {
        var a = 1, b = 1;
        function run(code)
        {
            var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })();
            console.log("test 3 is strict: " + isStrict);
            return new Function(`return (${code})`)();
        }
        return run("a+b");
    }

    function test4()
    {
        var a = 1, b = 1;
        function run(code)
        {
            "use strict";
            var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })();
            console.log("test 4 is strict: " + isStrict);
            return new Function(`return (${code})`)();
        }
        return run("a+b");
    }

    function test5()
    {
        window.a = 1, window.b = 1;
        function run(code)
        {
            "use strict";
            var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })();
            console.log("test 4 is strict: " + isStrict);
            return new Function(`return (${code})`)();
        }
        return run("a+b");
    }

    function onload()
    {
        try { console.log("test1 " + test1()); } catch(ex) {console.log("test1 " + ex);}
        try { console.log("test2 " + test2()); } catch(ex) {console.log("test2 " + ex);}
        try { console.log("test3 " + test3()); } catch(ex) {console.log("test3 " + ex);}
        try { console.log("test4 " + test4()); } catch(ex) {console.log("test4 " + ex);}
        try { console.log("test5 " + test5()); } catch(ex) {console.log("test5 " + ex);}
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:onload()">
</body>
</html>
```

The conclusion is that eval will do the job in both strict and non-strict mode, new Function won't in either mode with local variables, but will work fine with global variables. As VLAZ pointed out, it's a matter of environment. Running new Function creates a closure, but, unlike the case with a regular function, it's one that encapsulates only the global environment (see https://javascript.info/new-function).

I'd suggest that you use either the approach of test2 or test5.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going to rewind a little. What is causing it to work in my snippet but not in my env with ES6/Webpack? Is there a mechanism that creates a local context, and that makes that local context unavailable to a new Function()? Which mechanism is that?

Comment: In your snippet a and b are global variables, which falls under test5; I could speculate that in your other case they are local and fall under test4.